# ¿Cómo corregir este error en el datatable?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Error en el datatable, librería para crear tablas

```
    <script>
        let tabla1 = $("#tablaarticulos").DataTable({
            "ajax":{
                url: "datos.php?accion=listar",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "id"

                },
                {
                    "data": "nombre"
                },
                {
                    "data": "precio"
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "orderable": false
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "orderable": false
                },
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    targets: 3,
                    "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary botonmodificar'>Modificar</button>",
                    data: null
                },
                {
                    targets: 4,
                    "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary botonborrar'>Borrar</button>",
                    data: null   
                }
            ],
            "lenguage": {
                "url": "DataTables/spanish.json",
            },
        })
    </script>
```

Hola, buen día. Tengo un problema con el datatable no se muestra en el index.html, el error es

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function.
```

Dice que Datatables no es una función. La parte de json funciona todo excelente

Comment: No se ha cargado JQuery. No sabemos si lo incluiste en el documento generado por tu script PHP. Revisa la respuesta que ya tienes

Answer (score 0):

Amigo espero estes bien , ya anexaste a tu archivo los CDN de datatable ? recuerda que el Script debe ir mas abajo de los CDN del footer.

estos van en el head

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
```

estos van en el footer

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda que las aclaraciones se realizan como comentarios en la pregunta, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Según tengo entendido JQuery va en head y antes de Bootstrap